# javascript function not returning a value but will write to console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

This the data im getting from post is a simple object and the return value is always empty.  Its logging to the console fine.  any ideas?

```
function getTaskData(item){
    var returnText = '';
    $.post("index.php", {name: "getTaskData", pk: item.taskDataId}, function(data){
        console.log(data);///Object {taskData: "Also - whats up with this?"}
        console.log(data.taskData);///Also - whats up with this? 
        returnText = data.taskData;
},"json");
    return returnText;
}
```

Comment: see my answer here: http://pastebin.com/fVqTdvVr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code included in the block `function(data) { ...` is called a callback.  It will be aynchronously called when the server's ajax call has finished.  Whereas the `return returnText` will be called immediately.

Whatever you are going to do with the returntext (update DOM etc) will need to be done in the `callback` function